# How to move android google map camera with constant velocity and zoom

Tags: android, animation, camera, zooming, google-maps-android-api-2

I cannot find the way to move android google map camera with constant velocity and zoom.

For example, if the current zoom is 15, and calling

```
CameraPosition pos= CameraPosition
                                .builder(map.mMap.getCameraPosition())
                                .target(target)
                                .zoom(15)
                                .build();

mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(pos), duration * 1000, null);
```

it modifies the zoom 15 - > 12 -> 15
(the mid value depends on the distance)

My target is to show an object moving on the map with constant velocity and always keep it in the center of the map

Tried to call moveCamera in the ValueAnimator of the object, but then the map jumps. I need to move it smoothly

Answer (score 1):

Use fused API for location update and move the camera to the updated location

```
mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<android.location.Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(android.location.Location location) {
                    if(location!=null){
                        try{
                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());

                            String addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),
                                    location.getLongitude(), 1).get(0).getAddressLine(0);

                            marker_origin = new MarkerOptions().
                                    position(latLng).title(addresses)
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
                            mMap.addMarker(marker_origin);
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16.0f));


                            getPlacesData(latLng, "restaurant");
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

For further details check the android developer documentation

https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html